ITMS-90725: SDK version issue 17.4
This app was built with the iOS 16.2 SDK. Starting April 29, 2024, all iOS and iPadOS apps must be built with the iOS 17 SDK or later, included in Xcode 15 or later, in order to be uploaded to App Store Connect or submitted for distribution
I have the xcode version 15.3 and ios version 17.4
then also I am getting this error.What to do about it?

You don't have to do anything; it's just a warning. It isn't April 29 yet so the new rules are not strictly in effect yet anyway.

I got this in mail after I submitted my app in Test Flight.So I dont need to anything as of now?

Are you asking me to repeat what I already said?

I was just clarifying as I am about to release my app

Go ahead and release it. You should still try to track down what it is in your app that is building with the iOS 16.2 SDK, but you can do that later.

That I am doing but I still could not find any mention of 16.2 in entire code. The Xcode version is 15.3 and IOS Sdk is 17.4

check macos version you use, I think macos 13 has support for xcode 15
